# Reuse the weight matrix from embedding layer with @tf.function

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

Without using @tf.function, the script work perfectly

I want to use it to speed up training, but it's giving me error where I reuse the weight matrix from the embedding layers.

I think the error is caused by get_weights(), because it converts tensor back to numpy

I tried to use a tf.keras.layers.Dense instead of re-using the weights from embedding, and it worked perfectly.

```
class Example(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self,):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.embed_dim = embed_dim
        self.vocab_size = vocab_size
        self.embed = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(self.vocab_size, self.embed_dim)
        ...

    def call(self, inputs, trianing):
        ...
        embed_matrix = self.embed.get_weights()

        # a dense layer
        Vhid = tf.matmul(self.kernel, tf.transpose(embed_matrix[0]))
        pred_w = tf.matmul(pred, Vhid) + self.bias
```

In my train script.
I did

```
@tf.function
def train_step(x, y, training=None):

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        pred = model(x, y, training)
        losses = compute_loss(y, pred)

    grads = tape.gradient(losses, model.trainable_variables)

    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

    return losses

/home/thomas/projects/tf_convsent/models/.py:195 call  *
   embed_matrix = self.embed.get_weights()  # [vocab_size, 300]
/home/thomas/.conda/envs/tf2_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1177 get_weights
   return backend.batch_get_value(params)
/home/thomas/.conda/envs/tf2_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py:3011 batch_get_value
   raise RuntimeError('Cannot get value inside Tensorflow graph function.')

RuntimeError: Cannot get value inside Tensorflow graph function.
```

Answer (score 4):

Found the easiest solution which improved 50% training speed(122 hrs to ~65 hrs)

just change

```
embed_matrix = self.embed.get_weights()
```

to

```
embed_matrix = self.embed.weights
```

will do the trick.